# Are there restrictions on removing an enum value on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, enums

I'm trying to remove a value from an enum in Postgres and it has been failing. I've done this many times before with no issues so I'm not sure if something has changed or if I'm running into some edge case restriction.

Here is what I'm running (removing the enum `FOURTH`):

```
ALTER TYPE "my_enum" RENAME TO "my_enum_old";
CREATE TYPE "my_enum" AS ENUM('FIRST', 'SECOND', 'THIRD', 'FIFTH');
ALTER TABLE "my_Table" ALTER COLUMN "my_column" TYPE "my_eum" USING "my_column"::"text"::"my_enum";
DROP TYPE "my_enum_old";
```

Perhaps there is a size restriction on the length of the enum name? Our full enum name is the following length (Xs used to hide real name) `XXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXX_XXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXX_XXXXX_XXXX`
and when adding `old` to the end that adds another `_OLD`.

The error being returned is

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: my_enum = my_enum_old
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: Perhaps it is the name. According to my calculations, your _old extension puts it over the 63 character limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely problem is that you have a check constraint on the table which does something like:

```
 check (not(my_column = 'FOURTH'::my_enum_old)));
```

Once my_column changes type, that constraint can no longer be checked.  Just drop the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

By default [Postgres identifiers have a limit of 63 bytes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html). You should have gotten a warning like:

```
NOTICE:  identifier "XXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXX_XXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXX_XXXXX_XXXX_OLD" will be truncated to "XXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXX_XXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXX_XXXXX_XXXX_OL"
ALTER TYPE
```

You will have to choose a shorter identifier.

---

Note: while `XXX` and `xxx` are the same identifier, `"XXX"` and `XXX` are *different* identifiers. If sometimes you are double quoting and sometimes you are not, that could lead to problems.

This is why one should avoid quoting identifiers unless necessary.

---

Note that in this instance instead of recreating the enum, you could simply rename the value.

```
alter type my_enum rename value 'FOURTH' to 'FIFTH';
```

---

If you find yourself changing enums frequently, and having so many they require large identifiers, this may not be a good use of enums. Consider a join table instead.

```
create table thing_names (
  id bigserial primary key,
  label not null text
);

insert into things values
  (1, 'FIRST'), (2, 'SECOND'), (3, 'THIRD'), (4, 'FOURTH');

create table stuff (
  id bigserial primary key,
  thing_id bigint not null references things
);

insert into stuff values (1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 2);

select stuff.id, things.label
from stuff
join things on stuff.thing_id = things.id;

 id | label  
----+--------
  1 | FIRST
  2 | FOURTH
  3 | SECOND

update things set label = 'FIFTH' where id = 4;

select stuff.id, things.label
from stuff
join things on stuff.thing_id = things.id;

 id | label  
----+--------
  1 | FIRST
  2 | FIFTH
  3 | SECOND
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So we did notice the issue with the long enum and we tried shrinking the name to <50 characters. However, that still resulted in the same error I posted above.

re: not using enums, this is definitely one of our longest and we don't change them often, this is more of an exception than a norm

Comment: The only line in the above code where I couldn't shrink the name was in the original enum. i.e. line 1: `ALTER TYPE "my_full_length_enum" RENAME TO "shortened_enum_old";`. That line works but the error pops up on the 3rd line when the `ALTER COLUMN` is run with the operation not exists issue

Comment: `"XXX"` and `XXX` are different identifiers. The latter will be downcased to `xxx`. Is it possible sometimes you're using `"XXX"` and sometimes you're using `xxx`? Check the exact names of the types with `\dT` in psql`.

Comment: hmm nope, capitalization is all correct. I use quotes on all instances. The error says `operator does not exist: my_enum = my_enum_old` - I wonder why it wants to set them equal, maybe thats part of the override, but if so I don't see why it would ever work (those types can't be compatible since they are different right?)